# Get entity framework foreign key entity type name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I am currently working with the code first entity framework in C# and i am looking for a function to get the Entity name (not the property Name, but the name of the class) when all i have is the foreign key. Is something like this possible with reflection or something like that?

I have the following entities (simplified).

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int  DepertmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the OnModelCreation the relations are mapped like this.

```
HasRequired(t => t.Department)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Employee)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID);
```

So if I have the DepartmentID i whant to have the class name as string. ("Department").

Comment: Do you know what type the foreign key is? Normally you'd just grab the object and do `something.GetType().Name` - but without a way to get an instance of the object from your foreign key then you're not getting anywhere.

Comment: Does it mean that you have just integer value?

Comment: I have the name DelpartmentID. no value.